# Issue installing Android platform 2.1 on my windows 7 machine

Tags: android

i have installed latest SDK Revision 11  as of now and  have downloaded and installed Platform 2.3.3, 3 and 3.1

I need to develop an application for my 2.2 Version, and for that when i tried to install 2.2 
following error was thrown

```
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 2
File not found: C:\Program Files\android\temp\android-2.2_r02-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 2
File not found: C:\Program Files\android\temp\android-2.1_r02-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
File not found: C:\Program Files\android\temp\android-1.6_r03-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
File not found: C:\Program Files\android\temp\android-1.5_r04-windows.zip (Access is denied)  
Downloading Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files\android\temp\samples-3.1_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files\android\temp\samples-3.0_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files\android\temp\samples-2.3.3_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files\android\temp\samples-2.2_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files\android\temp\samples-2.1_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Android Compatibility package, revision 2
File not found: C:\Program Files\android\temp\compatibility_r02.zip (Access is denied)
```

Please help

Answer (score 4):

No need to move to other place as mentioned in ANSWER 1.
Run "SDK Manager.exe" as Administrator in Windows 7 then it will download the SDK from the Android site.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, `Program Files` is a protected folder. You could try installing the Android SDK into some other folder.

e.g. `C:\Android\SDK`

Comment: A better place would be another partition :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the platform 2.2 if you want to develop for it
Are you using Eclipse ?

Comment: yes , i have installed ADT, including 2 updates that eclipse detected automatically a few days ago

Comment: Thanks guys , http://www.coderanch.com/t/526550/Android/Mobile/Install-Android-platforms-Android-SDK helps